# How can I use p5.js sketch as loader for website?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

i have created a p5.js sketch and tried to implement it on my website as a loader… the problem is, that i have to load the p5.js sketch in the body part of my HTML because the sketch would still be visible after loading the page, if i put it in the head…

```
<body onload="myLoader()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader">
  <script src="sketch-loader.js"></script>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  //content of my website
</div>

<script>
var myVar;

function myLoader() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
```

thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Answered on [discourse.processing.org](https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-can-i-use-p5-js-sketch-as-loader-for-website/29890/3).

You are not actually attaching the p5js canvas to the “loader” div. And there are several ways to fix that, one is using [parent method](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent) (see also: [Positioning the Canvas](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Positioning-your-canvas)), another is using [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace) via the [p5 constructor](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p5), which takes an argument specifying the parent element for the canvas.

However, one other thing that bears noting, just hiding the div is potentially still going to leave the p5js sketch running and consuming resources. You would do well to also call [remove()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/remove) to completely stop the sketch.

Here's a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #loading_screen {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }
      
      body.loaded #loading_screen {
        display: none;
      }

    </style>
    <!-- if you include other heafty javascript files here, use the defer attribute -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <!-- this is where your SPA content will show up -->
      NOTHING TO SEE HERE YET
    </div>
    <div id="loading_screen">
      <!-- this is where the p5js loading screen canvas will be -->
    </div>
    <script>
      function LoadingScreen(p) {
        p.setup = function() {
          p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
        }

        p.draw = function() {
          p.background(200, 200, 200, 20);
          p.circle(
            p.width / 2 + p.cos(p.millis() / 400) * 100,
            p.height / 2 + p.sin(p.millis() / 400) * 100,
            100
          );
        }
      }

      let sketch = new p5(LoadingScreen, 'loading_screen');
      document.addEventListener('appLoaded', () => {
        // Make the loading screen go away
        sketch.remove(); // This removes the canvas
        document.body.classList.add('loaded'); // This stops displaying the div
      });

    </script>

    <script>
      <!-- Imagine this is some script that runs once your app is done bootstrapping 
      -->
    <!-- Where exactly this code goes depends on your SPA framework -->

    setTimeout(
      () => {
        let root = document.getElementById('root');
        root.innerHTML = 'Hooray our app has loaded!';

        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('appLoaded'));
      },
      5000 // simulate the app taking 5 seconds to load
    );
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```